# How to position container to fixed position?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div where I display next and previous blog post. I have the title in one container `(footer_post_title)` and the year and "read more button" in another container `(footer_post_buttons)`underneath. I need to have the second container stay in the bottom of the main container `(blog_image_footer)` no matter how long the title is in `(footer_post_title)`. How can I achieve this?

```
<div class="col-md-6 more-articles-left">
    <div class="more-articles previous">
        <div class="blog_image_footer">
            <div class="row artikkel-title-previous" style="height:100%; background: linear-gradient(24deg, rgba(167, 85, 194, 0.9), rgba(219, 197, 218, 0.9)), url('/files/blog_pictures/o-KID-EATING-facebook.jpg') no-repeat center center /cover">
                <div class="container footer_post_title">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <h1 class="blog_post_title_footer">How to teach Your kids to eat healthy</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="container footer_post_buttons">
                    <p class="blog_post_year_footer">December 2016</p>
                    <a href="article.php?article_title=how-to-teach-your-kids-to-eat-healthy" class="btn btn-default btn-footer-read-more" name="read-more-article">Read now!</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know whats the issue here.. This should push the second container(`footer_post_buttons`) when the title expands. This should already behave just like you wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `position: relative` to the container and `position: absolute` to its child so you will be able to position your child element taking as reference your parent element.

After that, you can set `bottom: 0` to the child so the child will be fixed at the bottom of its container.

```
.blog_image_footer{
    position: relative;
}

.footer_post_buttons{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: trying at the moment.

Comment: Yeah I could see myself working with that option. Thanks!

Comment: one more question. by any chance, can the footer_post_buttons be 100% width? because right now it is positioned on the left side of the main container

Comment: @raqulka Do you mean to center it on the container or that the child element will be 100% of the width?

Comment: child element to be 100% width

Comment: @raqulka Then just set `width: 100%`. This will take the 100% of the width of the container if the container has a certain width set. Here you have an example: https://jsfiddle.net/xczqfzsz/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use this basic principle:

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body, html{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
body{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#container
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:100%;
    background-color: white;
    border: 0.2em solid black;
    flex-shrink:0;
    flex-grow:1;
    display:flex;
}
#footer,#header
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
    height:1.5em;
    background-color: white;
    border: 0.2em solid black;
    flex-shrink:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
header here
</div>
<div id="container">
this is container
</div>
<div id="footer">
footer here
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using bootstraps grid system: 
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

This should allow you to make the h1 container responsive.